# Bat file directory listing, remove text enries

Tags: batch-file

i have a simple bat file that list directory files only.

```
if exist "output.txt" del "output.txt" 
dir /a /b /-p /O:N >>output.txt
```

when text file is created it also adds the bat file and the output.txt entries in the text file.  I would like to remove those 2 entries to make the final list clean.

Thanks and hope i explained it correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the batch file is named `list.bat`, with the help of `findstr` you can exclude the two files from the `dir` output.

Replace the second line with

```
dir /a /b /-p /O:N |findstr /vi output.txt|findstr /vi list.bat >>output.txt
```

BTW, the `if exist...` line is useless as the file `output.txt` is re-created by the `dir` command redirection before it starts to list the files.

Comment: Seki wrote: "the `if exist...` line is useless as the file `output.txt` is re-created by the `dir` command redirection before it starts to list the files". Not true; the `>>output.txt` redirection _appends_ the output, so in this case the `if exist...` is required.

Comment: @Aacini: Make the test : keep the `if exists... del` and remove the `findstr /vi output.txt` part : you will see there is always the `output.txt` listed. It was when I tried on my Win7.

Comment: @Seki: Excuse me. I am talking about the fact that `>>output.txt` _APPENDS_ the new info to the old contents of output.txt, so in this case the `if exists ... del ...` is required; this problem can be avoided by using `>output.txt` overwrite redirection instead of append as dbenham suggested. In any case, "output.txt" name must be removed from the list.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a small improvement over the Seki answer:

1) Use overwrite redirection instead of append

2) Eliminate both files using a single FINDSTR

3) Use `%~nx0` to get the name of the running batch file

```
@dir /a /b /-p /o:n|findstr /vi /c:"output.txt" /c:"%~nx0" >output.txt
```

Comment: One findstr, many match strings (I never tried that). Nice solution! +1

Answer (score 1):

The version below doesn't require FINDSTR, so it is faster:

```
@echo off
(for %%f in (*.*) do if "%%f" neq "%~NX0" if "%%f" neq "output.txt" echo %%f) > output.txt
```